# How to handle Twilio callback response in .Net core?

Tags: .net, .net-core, twilio, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

In My old asp.net application framework, I can receive Twilio Call Back message inside a generichandler form where i get the properties from context.Request.Form and context.Request.QueryString objects.
What would be the process of receiving twilio callback in an `ASP.NET` core web application?
In my controller action method should i  add some parameter or should i use same logic of Request object inside a a parameter-less action method?

Comment: Why should it be any different for Asp.Net Core?

Comment: You create an action to handle it, assign it a route, and then feed that route to Twilio as your callback. Not sure what part you're having difficulty with?